# Condition that checks wheter statement is false

Tags: scheme, racket

I am kind of struggling with this language. I am trying to make a condition, that executes only, when it is false. I have a function that returns false, but I have no idea how to do it. See code below:

```
(define p (make-queue))
(enqueue! p 1)
(enqueue! p 1)
(enqueue! p 2)
(enqueue! p 3)
(memq 5 (queue->list p))
(cond
  [(false? (memq 4 (queue->list p))) "yaay"]
  )
```

Basically I am creating a queue, then I am asking with memq, if there is a desired value in the list, which in my case returns false. And now I need to execute the "yaay" part. How can I achieve that? I tried asking for false, I tried `(= (#f) (memq 4 (queue->list p)))` or some simple ifs, but that does not work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to check the condition you want would be:

```
(cond
  [(not (memq 4 (queue->list p))) "yaay"])
```

Remember that in Scheme the *only* false value is `#f`, everything else is considered true - including `null`, `'()`, `0`, `""`, etc.

In this case, `memq` will return the *list* that starts with the searched element if it was found, or `#f` otherwise, and `not` negates the result, meaning that the condition is true only if the element isn't in the list.

One last thing - [`memq`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._memq%29%29) uses [`eq?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=equal%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq~3f%29%29) for comparing, it's a better idea to use [`member`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29), which uses [`equal?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=equal%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29) and is more general (and I think this is the reason why your code doesn't behave as expected); you should read in the documentation the difference between `equal?` and `eq?` to understand why this matters.